# why is my loop only seeing the value of the first array element?

Tags: javascript, .net, arrays

```
function Deal()
{

var suffledDeck:Array;
var playerOneCards: Array;
var playerTwoCards: Array;  
var first:int =0;
var second:int = 1;

suffledDeck = new Array();
playerOneCards = new Array();
playerTwoCards = new Array();

//var CardLeft:int = Deck.length;
for(var i = 0; i < Deck.length; i++) 
{   
    Debug.Log(Deck.length);

    var ranNum = Random.Range(1,Deck.length);

    suffledDeck.Add(Deck[ranNum]);

    Debug.Log("suffled deck: " + suffledDeck.length);
}

//var halfDeck: int = (suffledDeck.length / 2);

for(var j = 0; j <=26 ; j++)
{       
    Debug.Log(first);
    Debug.Log(second);

    playerOneCards.Add(suffledDeck[first]); 
    playerTwoCards.Add(suffledDeck[second]);

    Debug.Log(playerOneCards[first].img);   
    Debug.Log(playerTwoCards[second].img);  

    first += 2;
    second += 2;        
}
}
```

when i begin to split the array into 2 separate arrays it begins to ignore every element except the first element. the suffleDeck[] has 52 Card objects loaded in and im trying to split the array so that each player can have there own deck.

Console window for debug purpose: http://puu.sh/2dqZm

Comment: The Unity tag is for Microsoft Unity. Please don't misuse it.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is `var ranNum = Random.Range(1,Deck.length)`.

`ranNum` should be generating a random index between 0 to `Deck.length - 1` because array indices start at 0 (not 1).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with these logging statements:

```
Debug.Log(playerOneCards[first].img);   
Debug.Log(playerTwoCards[second].img);
```

`first` and `second` are valid indexes into `suffledDeck`, but each player's deck only has half as many cards. Try using `j` as the subscript in both logging statements instead of `first` or `second`.

You should also limit your loop to `j < 26`, not `j <= 26`. As it is, you are trying to put 27 cards in each player's deck.

Comment: but beings that the array starts at 0 and that means when i hit the 26th element it will end

Comment: @JoshBanks - Your loop currently tries to process 27 elements: index values 0, 1, 2, ..., 26. You want the last iteration to be for `j==25`, not `j==26`.

Answer (score 0):

because:

```
 Debug.Log(playerTwoCards[second].img);
```

here `second` value us 1 while your array contains only one item that is at zero. causing `ArgumentoutofRangeException`.

so try:

```
  for(var j = 0; j <=26 ; j++)
  {       
    Debug.Log(first);
    Debug.Log(second);

    playerOneCards.Add(suffledDeck[first]); 
    playerTwoCards.Add(suffledDeck[second]);

    Debug.Log(playerOneCards[j].img);   
    Debug.Log(playerTwoCards[j].img);  

    first += 2;
    second += 2;        
  }
```

Comment: i feel dumb now i did that same thing earlier thanks for the help.

Comment: my Pleasure :) give me a favor please accept correct answer for all your question by clicking green tick along with answer. It encourage users to help u.